# Adding new input control with javasscript attached and firing onclick from the browser

Tags: webbrowser-control

I have injected a new input control with javascript

```
 element = axWebBrowser.Document.CreateElement("input");
                element.SetAttribute("id", "inpinp");
                element.SetAttribute("type", "button");
                element.SetAttribute("value", "Hello World");
                element.SetAttribute("onclick", "javascript: alert('hello');");
```

its showing up the control in browser, but when i clicks no action.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This injects a button and then sets up an unobtrusive event listener to the click event:

```
HtmlElement myElem = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("input");
HtmlElement script = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");

dynamic element = myElem.DomElement;
element.SetAttribute("value", "Hello, World!");
element.SetAttribute("type", "button");
element.SetAttribute("id", "myButton");

dynamic elemScript = script.DomElement;
elemScript.text = "function bindEvent() { var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton'); if(myButton.addEventListener){ myButton.addEventListener('click',clicked,false);}else if(myButton.attachEvent){myButton.attachEvent('onclick',clicked);}} function clicked(){alert('clicked');}";
((HtmlElement)webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0]).AppendChild(myElem);
((HtmlElement)webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0]).AppendChild(script);
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("bindEvent");
```

Good luck!